# How to Fetch a file name from a folder with current Date and Time using Java Code

Tags: java

Am new to java automation and i have a scenario where i need to navigate to a particular folder, the folder has a list of files i need to filter by date and fetch a filename that got generated recently i.e. if the current time is 5:30pm i need to find the file name that got created between 5:28pm to current time (5:30pm)

This has to be achieved using Java code, File names in the folder
DOF_US_DELL_1.0_20160930_0516.CSV
DOF_US_DELL_1.0_20160930_0756.CSV
DOF_US_DELL_1.0_20161003_0346.CSV
DOF_US_DELL_1.0_20161003_0536.CSV
DOF_US_DELL_1.0_20161004_0747.CSV
DOF_US_DELL_1.0_20161005_0527.CSV

Here is a piece of code that helps me to fetch the list of files in a directory

```
File dir = new File("C:\\FolderName");
              FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
                 public boolean accept
                 (File dir, String name) {
                    return name.startsWith("DOF");
                }
              };
              String[] children = dir.list(filter);
              if (children == null) {
                 System.out.println("Either dir does not exist or is not a directory");
              } 
              else 
              {
                  System.out.println("# of the files in the folder is: "+children.length);
                  if(children.length>0)
                  {
                    for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) 
                    {
                      String filename = children[i];
                      System.out.println(filename);
                    }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      System.err.println("# of the files in the folder is: "+children.length);
                      fail("# of the files in the folder is: "+children.length);
                  }               
              }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Good luck.  Perhaps if you show us what you've tried to code in your question, we might be able to give you more specific help.

Comment: Hi Gilbert thanks for your response... i have edited my original post please check out if you can help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Here I am sorting files on the basis of their last updated time.

```
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.startsWith("cred");
            }
        };

        List<FileOrder> list = new ArrayList<FileOrder>();
        File dir = new File("/tmp/");
        for (File file : dir.listFiles(filter)) {
            list.add(new FileOrder(file.getName(), file.lastModified()));
        }

        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("Last updated file : " + (list != null ? list.get(0) : null));
```

Above code is part of main function.

Below code is separate class.

```
public class FileOrder implements Comparable<FileOrder> {
        private String fileName;
        private Long updationTIme = 0l;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "FileOrder [fileName=" + fileName + ", updationTIme=" + updationTIme + "]";
        }

        public FileOrder(String fileName, Long updationDate) {
            super();
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.updationTIme = updationDate;
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public Long getUpdationDate() {
            return updationTIme;
        }

        public void setUpdationDate(Long updationDate) {
            this.updationTIme = updationDate;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(FileOrder o) {
            return o.getUpdationDate().compareTo(this.getUpdationDate());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Am getting error "List<FileOrder> list = new ArrayList<FileOrder>();" in this line.    Error: FileOrder can not be resolved to a type

Comment: Create FileOrder a separate class and den try. I believe you have added code without thinking. I will add instructions